# Jquery toggle div on button click - not toggling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, button, toggle

I'm attempting to get a div to toggle when you click the button above it. I'm not sure what is wrong with my code, but it isn't working.

EDITED WITH STYLE TAGS IN CORRECT PLACES. The code still isn't working though.

CSS file:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
         /*CV Script*/

        <script>$(document).ready(function(){
            $('#button8').click(function(){
            $('#conference8').toggle('slow');
            });
            });
            </script>
       <style>
       #conference8 {
            padding-left: 4em;
        }
        .button {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 2px;
            font-size: .8em;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .button:active {
            transform: translateY(2px);
        }
    </style>
    </head>
```

HTML:

```
<button id="button8">Abstract</button>
        <div id="conference8">blah blah blah</div>
```

Comment: You need to declare css code inside the <style> tags for DOM parser to understand. Other than that, you code works just fine. Fixed here : https://jsfiddle.net/fvgLd018/

Comment: It's reassuring that the code works elsewhere, but it's just leaving me more baffled. I've added <style type="text/css"> in my style tags, but the div refuses to react when I click the button. I'm truly baffled, atm.

Comment: Follow the code here. This is exactly what you need to do : https://jsfiddle.net/fvgLd018/1/

Answer (score 1):

You CSS is in `<script>` tag. It should be in `<style>` tag.

```
<head>
    <STYLE type="text/css">
#conference8 {
            padding-left: 4em;
        }
        .button {
            display: inline-block;
            padding: 2px;
            font-size: .8em;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .button:active {
            transform: translateY(2px);
        }

        /*CV Script*/
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#button8').click(function(){
            $('#conference8').toggle('slow');
            });
            });
            </script>

    </head>
```

---

#### Working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button8').click(function() {
    $('#conference8').toggle('slow');
  });
});
```

```css
#conference8 {
  padding-left: 4em;
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  font-size: .8em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="button8">Abstract</button>
<div id="conference8">blah blah blah</div>
```

Comment: Could you clarify, please? I tried changing the <script> tags around the function to <style> tags instead, and there was no change in performance.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
#conference8 {
padding-left: 4em;
}
.button {
display: inline-block;
padding: 2px;
font-size: .8em;
cursor: pointer;
}
.button:active {
transform: translateY(2px);
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button8').click(function(){
$('#conference8').toggle('slow');
});
});
</script>
 </head>
<button id="button8">Abstract</button>
<div id="conference8">blah blah blah</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it! Thank you everyone (especially @DinoMyte for introducing me to jsfiddle.net).

The issue wasn't the code, but where it was placed. My CV is contained on a separate .php file and imported in, but I was putting the code in my stylesheet and not on the .php file. When I moved it over to cv.php, it cooperated just fine.